# How to access container environment variables with kubernetes env?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables

I'm trying to run my application on Kubernetes. My docker container have environment variables such as `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which are set in Dockerfile. I tried to change them in the yaml file like this:

```
env:
- name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  value: "foo:$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)"
```

The above configuration doesn't work, I just see `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo:$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)` in the pod. This method seems work for Kubernetes env variables such as `KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO`, but not for docker env variables.

My questions are:

1. I think the `env` settings in yaml are injected into docker before the running time of the container, so kubernetes cannot read the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Therefor it can't change the variable. Do I understand it right?
2. How to change container environment variables with kubernetes env? I know that I can set the env variables in the `command` field of yaml file, but that seems not clean and are there other ways to do that?
3. If Kubernetes can't change existed envs, does it mean that the env field in yaml file is designed to add new envs only?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kubernetes variable expansion syntax only works on things Kubernetes directly knows about.  Inside a container an environment variable could come from a couple of places (the Dockerfile `ENV` directive, the base container environment itself, setup in an entrypoint script) and Kubernetes doesn't consider any of these; it only considers things in the same container spec.  The [API definition of `EnvVar`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#envvar-v1-core) hints at this:

> Variable references $(VAR_NAME) are expanded using the previous defined environment variables in the container and any service environment variables.

You can't use this Kubernetes syntax to change environment variables in the way you're describing.  You can only refer to other things in the same `env:` block (which may come from ConfigMaps or Secrets) and the implicit variables that come from other Services.

(Changing path-type variables at the Kubernetes level doesn't make a lot of sense.  Since an image is self-contained, it already contains all of the commands and libraries it would need.  It's difficult in Kubernetes to inject more tools or libraries; it'd be better to install them directly in your image, ideally in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`, but failing that you can update `ENV` in a Dockerfile similar to how you suggest here.)

Comment: Thank you David. Your answer is really helpful. I have just one more question: what's the meaning of "implicit variables that come from other Services"?

Comment: Kubernetes [defines a couple of environment variables based on other Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables); the format matches the environment variables produced by the archaic Docker link functionality.  I wouldn't rely on these, but they're available in this context.